# Creating a complex box

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-shapes

http://jsfiddle.net/vcv8y4uc/1/

I've done a few things, and I'm using the grid system of bootstrap, as you can see.

I'm with some doubts.

It is wrong to set the width of the box that way?
How can I create these spears on top and in the footer of the box? Can anyone help me with this?

How can I make the 'SEXTAS E SÁBADOS' stay with a background 100% over the grid size and not the box?

Thanks!

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
        <meta name="O Pub Crawl Oficial de São Paulo" content="" />
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!--  Bootstrap CDN -->
        <!--  Animate CDN -->

    </head>
    <style type="text/css">
    .col-md-3 {
        position: relative;
    }
    .box {
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: #f98835;
        width: 250px;
        height: 50%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .dia {
        padding: 5px 0;
        width: 100%;
        color: white;
        background: black;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 20px;
        padding-top: 20px;
    }
    .black {
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: #000;
        width: 210px;
        height: 210px;
        background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/250/250/');
    }

    </style>
    <body>
    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="box">
                    <h1 class="dia">SEXTAS E SÁBADOS</h1>
                    <h1>VILA MADALENA</h1>
                    <div class="black"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="box">
                    <h1 class="dia">SEXTAS E SÁBADOS</h1>
                    <h1>VILA MADALENA</h1>
                    <div class="black"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="box">
                    <h1 class="dia">SEXTAS E SÁBADOS</h1>
                    <h1>VILA MADALENA</h1>
                    <div class="black"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="box">
                    <h1 class="dia">SEXTAS E SÁBADOS</h1>
                    <h1>VILA MADALENA</h1>
                    <div class="black"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would use an image for the top and bottom triangles (you could use the same one and rotate one of them) negative left/right margins for the black title background and box-shadows.

Comment: can you please explain better the negative left/right margins??

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/vcv8y4uc/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do this:

Use `linear-gradient` for those borders(`col-md-3:before` and `col-md-3:after`), set the `width` of `.dia` to total `width + 40px` and give it a `-20px` offset by setting `left: -20px`. I've removed the bootstrap and added `display: inline-block` to `.col-md-3`.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcv8y4uc/5/)

```css
.col-md-3 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 110%;
  margin: 25px;
}
.container {
  height: 400px;
}
.box {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #f98835;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
.dia {
  padding: 5px 0;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  width: 290px;
  left: -20px;
  position: relative;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.black {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #000;
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/250/250/');
}
.col-md-3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
}
.col-md-3:before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: linear-gradient(white 0%, transparent 0%), linear-gradient(125deg, #F98835 33.33%, transparent 33.33%) 0 0%, #F98835 linear-gradient(55deg, #F98835 33.33%, white 33.33%) 0 0%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white 0%, transparent 0%), -webkit-linear-gradient(125deg, #F98835 33.33%, transparent 33.33%) 0 0%, #F98835 -webkit-linear-gradient(55deg, #F98835 33.33%, white 33.33%) 0 0%;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(white 0%, transparent 0%), -o-linear-gradient(125deg, #F98835 33.33%, transparent 33.33%) 0 0%, #F98835 -o-linear-gradient(55deg, #F98835 33.33%, white 33.33%) 0 0%;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(white 0%, transparent 0%), -moz-linear-gradient(125deg, #F98835 33.33%, transparent 33.33%) 0 0%, #F98835 -moz-linear-gradient(55deg, #F98835 33.33%, white 33.33%) 0 0%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 0px 100%, 63px 32px, 63px 32px;
  background-position: -18% 0%;
}
.col-md-3:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  background: linear-gradient(white 0%, transparent 0%), linear-gradient(125deg, #F98835 33.33%, transparent 33.33%) 0 0%, #F98835 linear-gradient(55deg, #F98835 33.33%, white 33.33%) 0 0%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white 0%, transparent 0%), -webkit-linear-gradient(125deg, #F98835 33.33%, transparent 33.33%) 0 0%, #F98835 -webkit-linear-gradient(55deg, #F98835 33.33%, white 33.33%) 0 0%;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(white 0%, transparent 0%), -o-linear-gradient(125deg, #F98835 33.33%, transparent 33.33%) 0 0%, #F98835 -o-linear-gradient(55deg, #F98835 33.33%, white 33.33%) 0 0%;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(white 0%, transparent 0%), -moz-linear-gradient(125deg, #F98835 33.33%, transparent 33.33%) 0 0%, #F98835 -moz-linear-gradient(55deg, #F98835 33.33%, white 33.33%) 0 0%;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 0px 100%, 63px 32px, 63px 32px;
  background-position: -18% 0%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="box">
          <h1 class="dia">SEXTAS E SÁBADOS</h1>
          <h1>VILA MADALENA</h1>
          <div class="black"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="box">
          <h1 class="dia">SEXTAS E SÁBADOS</h1>
          <h1>VILA MADALENA</h1>
          <div class="black"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="box">
          <h1 class="dia">SEXTAS E SÁBADOS</h1>
          <h1>VILA MADALENA</h1>
          <div class="black"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="box">
          <h1 class="dia">SEXTAS E SÁBADOS</h1>
          <h1>VILA MADALENA</h1>
          <div class="black"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
.dia {
        position: relative;
        left: -12px;
        bottom: -26px;
        padding: 5px 0;
        width: 110%;
        color: white;
        background: black;
    }
```

and for the geometric forms you can use a `&befor` with your `.box` here is a link to how to drow geometric forms with `css` it could be useful in your case :

[The Shapes of CSS](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)